# Allow multiple occurrences of unordered XML elements via XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

How would I write an XSD that would validate the following two XML documents?

## 1

```
<Credits>
    <Director>Movie</Director>
    <Director>Movie</Director>
    <Director>Movie</Director>
    <Producer></Producer>
    <Producer></Producer>
    <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
    <Producer></Producer>
    <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
    <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
</Credits>
```

## 2

```
<Credits>
    <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
    <Director>Movie</Director>
</Credits>
```

---

Here is what I have so far, but this doesn't allow for the unordered option I have above:

```
<xs:element name="Credits">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Director" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" />
                <xs:element name="Producer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" />
                <xs:element name="Actor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" />
                <xs:element name="Writer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How would I have multiple repeating elements, in no particular order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XSD will validate both of your XML documents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Credits">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Director" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Producer" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Actor" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Writer" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```